# How to install only "build" or "dist" or output result of a library via npm

Tags: node.js, npm

A very simple command can install bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

However, it installs like 118 files in *3.3.7*. And from those files, all I need is a files inside **dist** folder.

Now I understand that it's not a big deal, yet because we're developing a distributed teleworking infrastructure, a solution to one of our problems requires that we reduce the amount of files to the least possible state.

Is there a way to tell npm to install only the output of a library, and not all of its source code?

Comment: For front-end stuff, I'd highly recommend either using a build tool such as [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Brunch](http://brunch.io/), and/or a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). It'll save you a lot of hassle in the long run. I rarely would ever deploy the entire contents of `node_modules` to the server for a front-end app - as you say, it's far too large.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the `--production` switch; this will ensure the `devDependencies` of your packages don't get installed.

```
npm install bootstrap --production
```

More documentation about the switch here - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Create a simple folder, and inside that empty folder run `npm install bootstrap --production`. Still you get the source code. Am I right?

Comment: The `--production` flag has no particular meaning when adding a dependency to a project. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install